# I want to know how to create a multi boot DVD with all the Ubuntu flavors (Kubuntu, lubuntu, Xubuntu and Ubuntu)

Tags: dual-boot, xubuntu, lubuntu, kubuntu, dvd

I am a computer teacher. I am introducing my students to Linux, and I wish to create a multi boot live-DVD (single layer, 4.5GB)  with all the Ubuntu flavors (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu and Ubuntu 14.04) to use it in class.
I have tried the following Windows utilities (because I am used to Windows, but I also have installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my computer):
- X-boot: the ISO image is too big to fit in a single DVD (it duplicates the ISOs).
- SARDU: only support certain flavors of Ubuntu (Ubuntu y Kubuntu)
- Magic ISO: created the ISO image successfuly, but it failed to recognize the blank DVD in the DVD unit. Tried to burn the ISO with Nero, but the DVD does not boot, an error message appears.

I got tired to search over the internet, so I hope someone could help me

Regards

Jorge Arce Ortiz

Comment: Dunno about multi boot DVD, but you can easily create multi boot USB. I have compiled the steps I had used here: http://commandlinewani.blogspot.in/2013/05/how-to-make-multi-partition-multi-boot.html

Answer (score 0):

You best solution would be to use 4 different LiveUSBs.  They boot faster and you can use the "Try Ubuntu, (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu) option without having to change anything on the computer you are using.  You will need to change the BIOS to boot from your LiveUSB for you first boot from USB.  Each LiveUSB should be of the 8Gb variety, 4 Gb probably will not allow enough room.  Easy to accomplish, once you have Ubuntu running simply use the "Create Startup Disk" utility in the Applications Launcher tell which ISO and where to place the image, it does the rest and the LiveUSB is created.

Maybe, not the answer you were looking for, but hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

MultiBootUSB allows you to install multiple live linux on a USB disk non destructively and option to uninstall distros. It's also multiplataform.

You only need to download the .deb package they offer at:

http://multibootusb.org/

Multisystem is not multiplataform but you can use it as a live CD when on need. Instructions to add the repository are aviable; you can also buy as CD or USB stick

http://liveusb.info/dotclear/index.php?pages/install